# Multiple Parse.com row images displaying in Collectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've got a single class, called "Collections".  In that class I have multiple columns for 'name', 'location', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3' and 'image4'.

If I was only dealing with a single image and a tableview, I'd have no trouble.  But I'm venturing outside what I know now, and can't seem to find any examples anywhere, dealing with Swift.  I see it mentioned that either using a small number of column file/images is ok (3-4 like I'm doing), and if you're using more to do a relation (whatever that is).
Unfortunately, I haven't found any examples of how to actually pull down the images (if they exist).

The code is below, but all it does is pull the image1 image, since I don't know how to get image2, image3, and image4 in the collection view as well.

... Deleted a bunch of non-working code here ...

Adding new code here:

Here's the variables:

```
class ParseCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

var currentObject : PFObject?
var collectionImages: [PFFile]?
var tappedObjectID: String!
var imageObject0: PFFile!
var imageObject1: PFFile!
var imageObject2: PFFile!
var imageObject3: PFFile!
var imageObject4: PFFile!
var imageObject5: PFFile!
var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
var collectionImage0: UIImage!
var collectionImage1: UIImage!
var collectionImage2: UIImage!
var collectionImage3: UIImage!
var collectionImage4: UIImage!
var collectionImage5: UIImage!
var imageView: PFImageView!
```

Here's the very ugly bit of code...  I'm sure this is the perfect job for an array, but I'm not sure how to do it yet:

```
    func loadCollectionViewData() {

    // Build a parse query object
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Collections")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:tappedObjectID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) records.")

            self.imageArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in objects! {

                self.imageObject0 = object["image0"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject0.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage0 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image0 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage0)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage0)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image0 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

                self.imageObject1 = object["image1"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage1 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image1 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage1)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage1)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image1 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

                self.imageObject2 = object["image2"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject2.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage2 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image2 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage2)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage2)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image0 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

                self.imageObject3 = object["image3"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject3.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage3 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image3 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage3)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage3)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image3 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

                self.imageObject4 = object["image4"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject4.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage4 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image4 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage4)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage4)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image4 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

                self.imageObject5 = object["image0"] as! PFFile
                self.imageObject5.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.collectionImage5 = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        println("Image0 successfully retrieved")
                        println(self.collectionImage5)


                    }

                    self.imageArray.append(self.collectionImage5)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    println("image5 imageArray: \(self.imageArray)")

                })

            }

        } else {
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error!, error!.userInfo!)
        }


    })

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

and here's the cell stuff:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParseCollectionViewCell

    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "question")

    cell.cellImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let tappedObject = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("CollectionViewToDetailView", sender: tappedObject)
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var detailObject : PFObject?
    if let imageArray = sender as? PFObject{
        detailObject = sender as? PFObject
    } else {
        // No cell selected in collectionView
        detailObject = PFObject(className:"Collections")
    }

    // Get a handle on the next story board controller and set the currentObject ready for the viewDidLoad method
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! ParseDetailViewController
    detailScene.detailObject = (detailObject)
    detailScene.currentObject = (currentObject)
}
```

Because of the random loading, I either need to figure out how to force the images to load in a certain order or I have to figure out which image is which when I tap on it so I can properly pass it onto the next viewcontroller, which is the detail viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make more UIImageViews (or PFImageViews) for the images in your cell, then just repeat what you have for the first image for the rest (but change their names to match the columns where they are store on parse)

Alternatively you may want to implement PFImageViews and use their file properties & loadInBackground() methods.

Edit: You can iterate through your received objects and place the images into a new array and use that for your collection view.

Code example:

```
var parseOjbect = ["image1":NSData(), "image2":NSData(),"image3":NSData(),"image4":NSData()]

var receivedParseObjects = [parseOjbect]

var photosForCollectionView = [NSData]()

for receivedParseObject in receivedParseObjects {

photosForCollectionView.append(receivedParseObject["image1"]!)
photosForCollectionView.append(receivedParseObject["image2"]!)
photosForCollectionView.append(receivedParseObject["image3"]!)
photosForCollectionView.append(receivedParseObject["image4"]!)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  My UIImageView is set in my custom UICollectionViewCell file.  I'd like to generate a 2 x 2 grid with each cell containing one image.  When I tap on an image, it'll push to a detailviewcontroller where I'll have the ability to change the image.  I've got the grid figured out, and the push segue figured out.  I'm also pretty sure I know how to change and update the image.  But I can't figure out how to display the separate 'file' rows and have them populate the grid.  I just get the one image1 image.

Comment: In your custom UICollectionViewCell file add more UIImageViews to accommodate the other image files.

Comment: Won't that jam all the images into a single cell instead of creating a grid of individual and separate collectionview cells, each with their own image (image1 for the first one, image2 for the second, etc...)?  I need each cell only to have one image per cell, because I plan on tapping on a cell and having it segue to a detailviewcontroller showing only the single image.

Comment: Got ya, then you can just create a new array that will hold your images, then iterate through your received parse data and add each image to the new array, then use that array to create your uicollectionview

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not quite sure where this code goes, but I'll play with it a bit and try to figure it out.

Comment: I'm still struggling to figure this out.  I put your block of code into the loadCollectionView function.  I also made numberOfItemsInSection photosForCollectionView.count.  I can't figure out what to properly change in the cellForItemAtIndexPath to display the individual images in each cell.

Comment: my code is just an example, where parseObject would be the object you get from parse (the row), the receivedParseObjects would be an array of parse objects, the for loop should happen after you receive your parse objects, (probably not in a collectionView method)

Comment: I think I'm getting ahead of myself a bit.  This probably isn't much of a Parse.com problem and is more of an array problem.  I'm not very good with arrays.  I may need to create another question that's more general about how to pull data from an array with names like image0, image1, image2, image3 and populate a collection view.  I think I need to get over that hurdle first, and then maybe I'll understand how to deal with getting the info from Parse.

Comment: That is also in my answer, just take it step by step

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  I've done a lot more reading and tinkering.  I still haven't solved it, but I think I'll figure it out in time.  Right now I've got a segue from a previous viewcontroller that's passing an array of PFObjects to the collection view controller.  This array is called currentObject, and contains only the data from the tapped row in a previous tableviewcontroller.  The array is holding a couple strings, a bool, and the image1-image4 files.  I'm still trying to figure out how I can dig into the array and pull out the images by themselves.

Comment: The array is holding PFObjects and all those other data types? Or are those data types part of the PFObject? You need to iterate through the array as shown in my answer with a for in loop. I will update with an example with objects that you can try in playground

Comment: The array is holding all of those types.  Here's a println of the array: `currentObject: Optional(<Collections: 0x7f82baee40d0, objectId: xcydAAcB5j, localId: (null)> {
atLocation = 0;
image1 = "<PFFile: 0x7f82baeeb4e0>";
image2 = "<PFFile: 0x7f82baeeaeb0>";
image3 = "<PFFile: 0x7f82baee8820>";
image4 = "<PFFile: 0x7f82baeec0f0>";
location = Home;
name = Test;
searchText = "test home";
})`

Comment: I think I managed to do it.  But man, is my code ugly.  However, the collection view loads up with the images properly.  Since the images load at different rates, they populate randomly each time I look at the viewcontroller, though.  Don't think that'll be an issue, though.  I don't know how to post code in a comment without it looking like junk or I'd copy/paste it up for you to take a look.

Comment: You can edit your original question with it or ask a new one